# Word meaning to interrogate in a "mild" manner?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The police started [...] the little kid.

In this case, I think *interrogating* is a little too severe. I thought of the word *questioning* but I think this can cause confusion (could mean they are *questioning his motives*).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without more context, I'd only offer _questioned_ or _probed_. If you're concerned about confusion, then add more to the sentence, a la: _The police started questioning the little kid about [the thing they're questioning him about]_

Comment: How *little* is this kid? Older or younger than seven for example?

Comment: Saying little kid is sort of redundant.  Child seems better.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Depends on your point of view. My son would tell you there's a huge difference between a little kid and a big kid, and he *definitely* counts himself among the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about quiz?

> **Quiz**
>
> *verb (used with object), quizzed, quiz·zing.*
>
> 5.to examine or test (a student or class) informally by questions.
>
> 6.to question closely: *The police quizzed several suspects.*
>
> 7.Chiefly British . to make fun of; ridicule; mock; chaff.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quiz

Answer (score 4):

They would refer to their questioning as an 'interview'/'formal interview' or the term 'inquiry'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **asking questions** may fit , if you are referring to a normal attitude not to scare the little kid.

*The police started asking the kid a few questions!*

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more possibilities if you rephrase the statement.

Specifically:

```
The police have been speaking with a little boy/girl
```

And you could qualify the severity or lack thereof with additional information, such as:

```
...regarding the incident.
...to ascertain the sequence of events.
...to get a clear picture of what has happened.
...to try to understand the incident.
```

Or more generally:

```
The police are following several lines of inquiry, which include a little boy/girl aged x
```

Answer (score -1):

To "grill" is a common slang, implying a serious level of questioning but without menacing overtones.

*"They took him down to the station and grilled him about the robbery."*

Comment: @Chenmunka That's not my understanding of the term in this context and I would have thought it appropriate. But that's the problem with slang, of course: without a formal definition it's open to personal interpretation.